# Calculating the rate of a logical vector in R

Tags: r

I'm a novice R programmer, so please excuse my programming language illiteracy. I have a data set with a logical vector as follows

```
2                 TRUE
3                FALSE
4                FALSE
5                FALSE
6                FALSE
7                FALSE
8                 TRUE
9                FALSE
10               FALSE
11               FALSE
12               FALSE
13               FALSE
14                TRUE
15               FALSE
16               FALSE
17               FALSE
18               FALSE
19               FALSE
20               FALSE
```

I need to calculate the "rate" which would be the total # of "TRUE" observations/total observations (in this case would be 3/20). I know I could do this by hand, but I need to automate it so as more observations occur, the rate will change. What function should I use?

Comment: assuming your vector is `v`, how about `sum(v) / length(v)`? `sum()` basically adds up the number of `TRUE` values (because `TRUE = 1` and `FALSE = 0` when summing a logical vector) while `length()` counts the total number of elements in the vector.

Comment: also, in the future you can use `dput()` to get an output that other users can copy/paste to recreate variables. It is useful when making reproducible examples: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: `mean(v)` should work.

Comment: Got it, this is definitely stuff I need to learn.